# Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21] Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting the following error:

```
Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21].
```

I have tried both debit and credit cards which is supported by VISA/Master service provider & so from Google cloud has any option to verify my card and approve to enable my billing account. Because of this, I unable to upgrade Firebase "Blaze".

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/78451829?hl=en, "or contact us" - I think that's the way to go.

Comment: First contact your bank/card-provider and ask them if they are blocking Google Cloud from charging. This recently happened to me when I tried to update my account with a new credit card.

Comment: Have you tried to contact [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your issue is related to the known issue with creating GCP billing accounts.

Please follow [this issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186210363) at the Google Public Issue Tracker to be updated. Feel free to add comments, CC yourself to receive emails with updates and press `+1`.